# Spring JPA projection with sublist

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, response, sublist

I have question about creating native query with custom response (spring projection) with nested „custom“ sublist i.e. i am trying to generate JSON output with nested sublists.

Child entity is:

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)

    private String secondName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    private Date dateOfBirth;

    private String phone;   

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="child_id")
    private List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
//...
}
```

Parent entity is, for example:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String secondName;

    private Date dateOfRegistration;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> child = new ArrayList<Child>();
    //...
}
```

Projection interface:

```
public interface ChildProjectionInterface {

    public int getParentId();

    public Date getFirstName();

    public List<ChildResponse> getChildData();

    interface ChildResponse {

        public int getChildID();
        public String getFirstName();

    }
}
```

Query (but, obviously, doesn't working):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.id AS parentId, p.firstName AS firstName, c.id AS childData.childId, c.firstName AS childData.firstName FROM parent p LEFT JOIN child c ON p.child_id = c.child_id AND p.secondName = :secondName", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ChildProjectionInterface> getListWithSubList(@Param(value ="secondName") String secondName);
```

I was reading and researching and trying..but nothing works (I saw https://medium.com/swlh/spring-data-jpa-projection-support-for-native-queries-a13cd88ec166, saw "for json auto" clause but not for spring jpa, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try jpa fetch operator?

```
@Query("select p from parent p left join fetch p.child c where p.secondName = :secondName")
```

Comment: In mysql sintax near to fetch. But, this idea doesn't address JPA custom sublist issue, anyway?

Comment: The issues is how to get { parentId: 1, firstName: "name", { childId: 1, firstName: "name"} , {childId: 2, firstName: "name"}} etc...